# Filter multidimensional array by value in array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-filter

This is my array:

```
$myArray = array(
    array("name"=>"Andrea", "Age"=>17),
    array("name"=>"Tresna", "Age"=>20),
    array("name"=>"Aria", "Age"=>12)
);
```

I want to filter that multi array by value in array. This is my filter:

```
$filter = array("Andrea", "Aria");
```

So the result must be like this:

```
$newArray = array(
    array("name"=>"Andrea", "Age"=>17),
    array("name"=>"Aria", "Age"=>12)
);
```

how to do like that?

Comment: Instead of filtering on a whitelist, here is filtering with the same structures, but with a blacklist: [Filter 2d array by a flat, blacklist array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50784166/2943403)

Answer (score 5):

The hint is already there, to *filter*, use `array_filter`.

Don't forget to use `use` keyword to import your criteria.

Example:

```
$newArray = array_filter($myArray, function($e) use ($filter){
                                                //    ^ import criteria
    return in_array($e['name'], $filter);
});
```

Comment: https://3v4l.org/hGYfl

Answer (score 0):

```
$myArray = array(
    array("name"=>"Andrea", "Age"=>17),
    array("name"=>"Tresna", "Age"=>20),
    array("name"=>"Aria", "Age"=>12)
);
$filter = array("Andrea", "Aria");

foreach($myArray as $arr)
{

    foreach($filter as $value)
    {
        if(in_array($value,$arr))
        {
            $finalArr[]=$arr;
        }
    }

}
```

$finalArr is your result

Comment: Shouldn't this be directly checking the `name` attribute?

Comment: This code-only answer is not tested and is incorrect.