# Filter 2d array by a flat, blacklist array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, filtering, array-difference

I have an array that looks like this..

```
$breadcrumbs = [
    ['Home', 'homepage.html'],
    ['About', 'aboutpage.html'],
    ['Contact', 'contactpage.html']
];

$remove = ['Home'];
```

I am trying to use `array_diff()` to remove the `Home` entry from `$breadcrumbs` like this:

```
return ( array_diff($breadcrumbs, $remove) );
```

It is not working and giving me "Array to string conversion" errors, where am I going wrong?

Comment: `array_diff()` on a multi dimensional array with a normal array?? I don't think that's possible

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter multidimensional array by value in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38965541/filter-multidimensional-array-by-value-in-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a bit of array gymnastics, you can convert the breadcrumbs array into an associative array, keyed by the first item, then use [`array_diff_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php) with the `$remove` array flipped (convert the values to keys).

```
$breadcrumbs = array_column($breadcrumbs, null, 0);
$breadcrumbs = array_diff_key($breadcrumbs, array_flip($remove));
print_r($breadcrumbs);
```

If you want the end array to be a 0 based array without string keys, add

```
$breadcrumbs = array_values($breadcrumbs);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_filter` to filter the array. Use `in_array` to check an array consist of a string.

```
$breadcrumbs = array(
    array('Home','homepage.html'),
    array('About','aboutpage.html'),
    array('Contact','contactpage.html')
);

$remove = array('Home');

$result = array_filter($breadcrumbs, function($o) use ($remove) {
    return !in_array( $o[0], $remove );
});

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $result );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will return:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => About
            [1] => aboutpage.html
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Contact
            [1] => contactpage.html
        )

)
```

---

**Another option,** if you only need the page name (element 0), you can use `array_column` to convert the multi dimensional arrray into a simple array.

```
$result = array_diff( array_column($breadcrumbs, 0), $remove);
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [1] => About
    [2] => Contact
)
```

Answer (score 0):

By chunking the `$remove` array to form a 2d array with single-element rows, you can enjoy the code brevity of `array_udiff()`.

In the callback, just compare the first elements.

This approach avoids the need to make iterated function calls like `in_array()`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/BGTnH))

```
var_export(
    array_udiff(
        $breadcrumbs,
        array_chunk($remove, 1),
        fn($a, $b) => $a[0] <=> $b[0]
    )
);
```